# Difference in days between two dates

Tags: c++, beginner, datetime

I've been trying to write a really basic function to determine the difference (in days) between two dates. I am **very** new to C++ so as you can imagine I am very happy with my work.
This function is part of a much larger code so I have missed off my includes, but the function does compile without warnings.

Just looking for some constructive criticism that a reasonable beginner can take on board.

I should add, this function takes two dates as strings in British format DD/MM/YYYY.

```
int dateDiffs(std::string date1, std::string date2){

    int startYear, endYear;
    int startMonth, endMonth;
    int startDay, endDay;

    int startInDays, endInDays;

    std::map<int,int> daysInMonth;

    daysInMonth[1]=31;
    daysInMonth[2]=28;
    daysInMonth[3]=31;
    daysInMonth[4]=30;
    daysInMonth[5]=31;
    daysInMonth[6]=30;
    daysInMonth[7]=31;
    daysInMonth[8]=31;
    daysInMonth[9]=30;
    daysInMonth[10]=31;
    daysInMonth[11]=30;
    daysInMonth[12]=31;

    startYear = atoi(date1.substr(6,4).c_str());
    startMonth = atoi(date1.substr(3,2).c_str());
    startDay = atoi(date1.substr(0,2).c_str());

    endYear = atoi(date2.substr(6,4).c_str());
    endMonth = atoi(date2.substr(3,2).c_str());
    endDay = atoi(date2.substr(0,2).c_str());

    startInDays = (startYear * 365) + (startMonth * daysInMonth[startMonth]) + startDay;
    endInDays = (endYear * 365) + (endMonth * daysInMonth[endMonth]) + endDay;

    return (endInDays - startInDays);
}
```

Comment: Would be a lot easier to calcularte the difference in seconds. Then convert that to days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a number of problems with this:

- The code as provided does not compile; you haven't shown what `#include` directives you've used.
- You don't validate the input to make sure it is in the proper DD/MM/YYYY format.
- You don't validate the parsed year, month, and day to make sure it makes sense. (For instance, you allow negatives, and any month number or day number)
- You don't handle the case when the month number is outside the [1..12] range. This will lead to undesirable behavior (it returns 0 for the month length and expands the map)
- You assume all years have 365 days. This completely ignores leap years (366 days with February having 29 days)

And a few stylistic issues:

- This code should be part of a class rather than just a bare function
- Questionable data type choice. You use a `std::map<>` instead of a regular array (an `int[]`); this slows things down with the only benefit being that you assume the month length is 0 instead of referencing memory outside the array.
- Duplicated code (the date parsing). This should be abstracted out to a separate function (hopefully including the validation and checking)
- Unnecessary parens around the return value.
- You initialize the data table each time; this should be stored in a separate class so it can be created once and then referenced.

Comment: Well, in the interest of baby steps:

I've ditched the std::map and have incorporated an array into part of my validation by making a "months limits" array:

    `unsigned int dayLimits[13] = {1, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};`

Answer (score 4):

@Snowbody has addressed many important points.  I'll just talk about the `std::map`.

The function initializes `daysInMonth` each time, which is just unnecessary.  You should have it initialized only once elsewhere, and it should also be `const` since it's not to be modified within the code.

If you have C++11 (which you should), you can initialize the map with an initializer list:

```
const std::map<int, int> daysInMonth = { {1, 31},
                                         {2, 28},
                                         {3, 31},
                                         {4, 30},
                                         {5, 31},
                                         {6, 30},
                                         {7, 31},
                                         {8, 31},
                                         {9, 30},
                                         {10, 31},
                                         {11, 30},
                                         {12, 31} };
```

(it can be formatted in any way you'd like)

You should also use an unsigned type for dates since they cannot be negative.

Answer (score 0):

I will not be marking this as the "answer to my question" but wanted to show how I have taken your advice on board:

I have written the following class:

```
unsigned int dayLimits[13] = {1, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

class userDate {

    public:             
        unsigned int uYear, uMonth, uDay;

        bool valiDate(unsigned int uYear, unsigned int uMonth, unsigned int uDay){
            if ((uYear >= 2000) && (uYear < 2100)) {
                if ((uMonth > 0) && (uMonth <= 12)){
                    if((uDay >= dayLimits[0]) && (uDay <= dayLimits[uMonth])){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        };

}startDate, endDate;
```

Comment: If you'd like this reviewed, post it as a new question.

Comment: You don't account for leap years.  Search the web for "Leap year calculation" and there will be many.  There is even an example in Wikipedia.